# SpringRestDocs and mocking MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I'm trying to generate API documentation using SpringRestDocs and SpringBootTest and MockMVC.

Our service uses MongoDB as storage and we have various services that talk to MongoDB using repositories.

In my test I'm mocking the services to not rely on MongoDB or data.

Though my tests run fine only if I've a local mongo running on my machine, otherwise tests fail because `org.mongodb.driver.cluster` is not able to connect.

Here is the error I get:

```
018-03-06 11:42:05.620  INFO 56095 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted

2018-03-06 11:42:05.724  INFO 56095 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

I would like to totally bypass MongoDB because I don't need it to build my documentation.

I've tried to use `@MockBean` on all the repositories that use Mongo and disable autoconfiguration, but still not working properly

Any suggestion on what shoudl I do to mock the MongoDB client/template?

Here is my `ApiDocumentation.java` class, without

package uk.ac.ebi.biosamples.docs;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException; 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.data.domain.*;
import org.springframework.hateoas.MediaTypes;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.restdocs.JUnitRestDocumentation;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import uk.ac.ebi.biosamples.model.Curation;
import uk.ac.ebi.biosamples.model.CurationLink;
import uk.ac.ebi.biosamples.model.Sample;
import uk.ac.ebi.biosamples.model.filter.Filter;
import uk.ac.ebi.biosamples.service.*;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.document;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.operation.preprocess.Preprocessors.*;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.request.RequestDocumentation.parameterWithName;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.request.RequestDocumentation.requestParameters;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApiDocumentation {

    @Rule
    public final JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private SamplePageService samplePageService;

    @MockBean
    private SampleService sampleService;

    @MockBean
    CurationPersistService curationPersistService;

    @MockBean
    CurationReadService curationReadService;

    @MockBean
    private BioSamplesAapService aapService;

    private DocumentationHelper faker;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.faker = new DocumentationHelper();
        this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)

                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation).uris()
                    .withScheme("https")
                    .withHost("www.myhost.com")
                    .withPort(443)
                )
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Generate the snippets for the API root
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void getIndex() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/").accept(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(document("get-index", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()), preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())));

    }

    /* Bunch of other similar tests */
}
```

Comment: try to exclude MongoAutoconfiguration

Comment: In the case that mongo maybe a necessary dependency, you can use `@DataMongoTest` instead of `@SpringBootTest`. This will use an in memory mongodb and you tests should execute fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue using an embedded mongodb instance.

For my specific needs this was sufficient to solve my issues with autoconfiguration.

In my pom I've added a dependence to `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and add a plugin to  start/stop the embedded mongodb before/after mvn build

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.joelittlejohn.embedmongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedmongo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>stop</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Not a good solution for the rest of us though.